# Is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have 101 rep because I frequent other stackoverflow sites.  So my rep is 1 (starting) + 100 (from other sites)  However, I was reading a question and I was shown the following message.

```
protected by Community ♦ yesterday

Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site. 

Would you like to answer one of these unanswered questions instead?
```

I wasn't particularly interested in responding but it seems like its not counting the rep awarded from other sites.  (second class rep points?)  Is this intentional or is this a 'feature'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Feature:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765

> ## Who can answer a protected question?
>
> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question.
> However, the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check,
> so you must have earned 10 or more reputation on that specific site to
> answer a protected question.